# How can I rebuild libraries with Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm using an SFML to train before creating and releasing an actually playable game. The problem is loading textures, fonts and other stuff from files. Every time I try, I get a following error:

```
undefined reference to `sf::Font::loadFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

I learned that I have to rebuild the libraries with the compiler that I use. I open the headers and build and run them, but every time a window with this message pops up:

> It seems that this file has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?

I click "Yes" but it pops up again and doesn't want to stop, neither does it rebuild the files. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what "I opened headers, build and run them" means, but if I get it right you did not build anything at all.

So, if you want to build SFML, there is pretty good instruction: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/compile-with-cmake.php

Using SFML with Code::Lite is described in the following tutorial: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-cb.php (note that this is about Code::Blocks, but Code::Lite is very similar).

If you have some specific questions about those tutorials feel free to ask.

Comment: I followed everything in the first tutorial and cmake doesn't want to build at all, it keeps spitting out these errors: `CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

Comment: Hmm... I believe that you have Windows, right? Are you sure you have mingw installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have mingw installed and it's compatible with my windows.